# How to do table mapping in ServiceNow (defects) with Azure DevOps (Impediments and Bugs)?

Tags: azure-devops, servicenow

**ServiceNow table,**

[image]

**AzureDevOps table.**
[image]

By default Epics and Product Backlog get mapped, we can easily synchronize change on some fields of Epics or Product backlog ( not all)
[image]

**How to do mapping with Bug, Impediment (Azure DevOps) with  Defects (ServiceNow) ?**

below is default mapping between Azure DevOps and ServiceNow
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on R&D i am able to integrate Azure devops **Bug** with **Defects** in ServiceNow

step1 : click on New
[image]

Step2 : fill correct internal table (serviceNow table) , external table (azure devOps) and click on NEW button.

[image]

Step 3 : External field System.Title since i am only using Title field for testing , you can add more as per as your requirement. and click UPDATE button.
System.Title , System. is prefix and Title or any field name you can get it from Azure Boards.

[image]

Step 4 : don't forget to click on Validate and Fix Mapping which give your mapping is correct or not.

[image]

Comment: we can find full steps in shared document
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JpDgNleTkP8yh1nEtM2kBGSXL8RL8Wxs/view

Comment: Hi Anish, Thanks for the sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.